# Eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $f(A)$ where $f$ is a polynomial and $A$ is a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

It is known that for an $n \times n$  real matrix $A$, and a polynomial
$$f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + ... + a_m x^m,$$
then if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ associated with eigenvector $v$, then
$$f(A)v = f(\lambda)v.$$
Let's say we have
$$f(x) = 1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^7.$$

Does this just mean that, if $\lambda = \alpha + \beta$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then
$$f(\lambda) = \sum_{n=0}^{7} (\alpha + \beta)^n$$
is an eigenvalue of $f(A)$? And the eigenvectors are the same for both $A$ and $f(A)$?

Please tell me if this would be correct for this question, because this does not seem that intuitive.

Comment: I don't understant the part: "$\lambda=\alpha+\beta$" is an **eigenvector** of $A$. I think the notation  is not usual.

Comment: @Alexander eigenvalue! sorry!

Answer (score 1):

If $Ax=\lambda x$, then $p(A)x=p(\lambda)x$ for any polynomial $p$. You can pick up extra eigenvalues when you apply polynomials. For example, $p(A)=0$ will occur if the minimal polynomial for $A$ divides $p(\lambda)$; then every non-zero vector is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $0$. So you may have more eigenvectors of $p(A)$ than you do for $A$.

Answer (score 0):

In general the result state:

Let $A\in \mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ such that:

- $A\cdot A^{\ast}=A^{\ast}\cdot A$.
- $U^{\ast}\cdot U=U\cdot U^{\ast}=I$.
- $U^{\ast}AU={\rm diag}(\lambda_{i})_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}$.
- $Av_{i}^{\lambda_{i}}=\lambda_{i}v_{i}^{\lambda_{i}}$.

Then

- $f(A)w_{i}^{f(\lambda_{i})}=f(\lambda_{i})w_{i}^{f(\lambda_{i})},$ where $\displaystyle f(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{m}c_{k}t^{k}$.

Comment: This isn't really an answer because in the question set  your first three bullet points may not be satisfied.